# MS Residual functions in R

Tags: r, statistics, stat

Is there a pre-defined function to find Mean Square Residual (MS Residual) in the R programming language? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `library(sos); ???residual` ?  Which is to say, have you used any of the R search tools to see what might be useful?

Comment: I bet there is, but you'll have to be much more specific.  Currently this is much too general to be answered.  Maybe give a concrete example of your problem.  What have you tried?  What is the input and desired output?  What type of problem are you solving?

Comment: Not sure how to be more specific Justin, just looking for the name of the function to find ms residual, it should look something line: msresidual()

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about a regression type model... I don't know of one function, but if you are willing to use two you can create a new one (or just use the two).

```
msResid <- function(model) deviance(model)/df.residual(model)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `summary(model)$sigma^2` is inefficient if all you want is the MS Residuals.